# why it was failed SetFilePointer()?

Tags: winapi

```
BOOL SetDeviceID(HANDLE device,char *id){//
    char data[2];
    data[0]=0x02;
    data[1]=0x27;

    DWORD dwPtr=SetFilePointer(device,0x33,//distance
                                NULL,//
                                FILE_BEGIN);
    if(dwPtr==INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) cout<<GetLastError()<<endl;
    BOOL result=WriteFile(device,data,2,NULL,NULL);
    //cout<<GetLastError()<<endl;

    if(result==false)cout<<"Fail WRITE    "<<endl;
    return TRUE;
}


HANDLE GetDeviceHandle(char *path){
    HANDLE handle= CreateFile(LPCSTR(path),
               GENERIC_ALL,//
               0,
               NULL,
               OPEN_EXISTING,
               NULL, 
               NULL);
    if(handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    cout<<"fail to createfile()"<<endl;
    exit(1);
    }
    else return handle;

}
```

this is some code of my works.

I am going to read/write directly device(usb)

on ReadFile() case, It was successful.

But, I have tried to call SetFilePointer

But GetLastError returned 87. it means invalid input

What is the problem? on my code

shortly, CreateFile,ReadFile is ok but SetFilePointer and WriteFile failed

Comment: what is `device`, where do you get it? Your code does not look sufficiently relevant and clean.

Comment: device is from main()
please assume HANDLE parameter is valid.
I already checked this value with ReadFile()

Comment: Yes in my case device is usb

Comment: By the way, don't declare the function `HANDLE GetDeviceHandle(char *path)`. That compels you to cast to `LPCSTR`. Instead declare the param `const char *path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are directly accessing a disk device you cannot seek to positions in the middle of a sector. The position must always be a multiple of the sector length. And `0x33` is not a mutiple of your sector length.

What you will need to do is read an entire sector. Modify the bytes that need to be modified. And finally write back the entire sector.

Comment: Oh Thank you I will always keep in mind.
And again i need your help.
Sometime, CreateFile() GetLastError() return 32 that means ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
But Any process don't Access my usb...(my opinion)
Do I additionally edit argument CreateFile? or else?
only my app approach my usb (that was guranted)
And When I tried to WriteFile, My usb is updated following my code.
But It caused abort app.How can I debug my program?;;;;

Comment: Hard to say. I'd be inclined to believe Windows and assume that something else is accessing the drive.

Comment: Ok Windows could access my device But
on App level, only one app can access my device

Comment: My guess is that it is the system that is accessing it. Are you sure that you need to use direct access to achieve your needs? My guess is that there are APIs to do what you do here.

Comment: I want to edit my device low level like Winhex.
When calling WriteFile(), It doesn't return and abort process.
I am going to put the label in device (some sector).

Comment: if WriteFile will successfully return some value, I achieve all my needs about CreateFile,ReadFile,WriteFile

Comment: So long as you use sector aligned read and writes, then you should be fine. I think I answered the original question here, no?

Comment: Yeah original question is resolved by your answers.
And I may request that why WriteFile() Functions was't returned ,but write my device. It cause kill my process. 
sector aligned solved read,setpointer, but writefile wasn't....

Comment: It is sorry to unintentionally change WriteFile 4th argument
All things go well