# SetFilePointer from FILE_END always fails for a volume handle

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I simply want to move the file-pointer of a volume handle backwards from `FILE_END`. Unfortunately, the operation fails regardless of any input value I pass to it !

I'm using the following code:

```c
HANDLE vol_handle = CreateFile ("\\\\.\\C:",
                         GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                         FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                         NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

if (vol_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Failed to create volume handle!\n");
    print_last_error(GetLastError());
    return ERROR;
}
printf("Handle acquired for volume %s \n", VOLUME);

long int dist = 512000; // 500 KB forwards

SetLastError(0);
int result = SetFilePointer (vol_handle, dist, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
if (result == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
{
    printf("SetFilePointer (BEGIN) FAILED!\n");
    print_last_error(GetLastError());
}
else
    printf("SetFilePointer (BEGIN) SUCCESS!\n");

dist = -5120; // 50 KB backwards

SetLastError(0);
result = SetFilePointer (vol_handle, dist, NULL, FILE_END);
if (result == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
{
    printf("SetFilePointer (END) FAILED!\n");
    print_last_error(GetLastError());
}
else
    printf("SetFilePointer (END) SUCCESS!\n");

SetLastError(0);
result = SetFilePointer (vol_handle, dist, NULL, FILE_CURRENT);
if (result == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
{
    printf("SetFilePointer (CURRENT) FAILED!\n", offset_low_part);
    print_last_error(GetLastError());
}
else
    printf("SetFilePointer (CURRENT) SUCCESS!\n");
```

The output:

```
  Handle acquired for volume \\.\C:
  SetFilePointer (BEGIN) SUCCESS!
  SetFilePointer (END) FAILED!
     Error 0x57: The parameter is incorrect.
  SetFilePointer (CURRENT) SUCCESS!
```

As you can see, the seek works fine for `FILE_BEGIN` and `FILE_CURRENT`, but it always fails for `FILE_END` with error code `0x57` (87 in decimal) saying:

```
  The parameter is incorrect
```

Note that changing `dist` to a positive value doesn't change the situation.

What am I missing here?

**( NOTE: Testing on Windows-5.1.2600 (XP SP3) in latest Code::Blocks IDE 16.01 with MinGW compiler, and Administrator privileges )**

---

**NOTE:** This is absolutely not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382356/), since I am not accessing physical disk (volume access is different from physical disk) and the distance value is a multiple of 512 bytes (the logical sector size). If the distance length was incorrect, then the other seeks (BEGIN and CURRENT) would have failed as well, yet they don't.

---

#### Update

Based on [Rohans'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738926/37739935#37739935) answer, I performed another check with the following code:

```c
long long int offset_64 = 5120000 // 5000 KB distance;
long int offset_low_part = -(0xffffffff & offset_64);
long int offset_hig_part = offset_64 >> 32;

printf("offset_64 = %lld\n", offset_64);
printf("low_part  = %ld\n", offset_low_part);
printf("high_part = %ld\n\n", offset_hig_part);

// Get volume handle using CreateFile(...) exactly as before;

SetLastError(0);
int result = SetFilePointer (vol_handle, offset_low_part, &offset_hig_part, FILE_END);

if (result == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER)
{
    print_last_error(GetLastError());
    printf("Failed to set file pointer!\n");
    printf("high_part after SetFilePointer = %ld\n", offset_hig_part);
    return ERROR;
}
```

Although I believe Rohans' point is important, it still doesn't solve the problem:

```
offset_64 = 5120000
low_part  = -5120000
high_part = 0

Handle acquired for volume \\.\C:
Error 0x57: The parameter is incorrect.
Failed to set file pointer!
high_part after SetFilePointer = 0
```

Using a positive value for `low_part` doesn't change the situation.

---

#### Update

Based on David Heffernan's comment below, I acknowledge that this code can be shorter and easier using `SetFilePointerEx`, but the result is still the same and the operation fails to seek from `FILE_END` on the volume handle.

Comment: `printf("SetFilePointer (BEGIN) FAILED!\n");` Off-topic, but you shouldn't risk calling functions that may wind up setting the error flag.  You should utilize the value of `GetLastError` as soon as possible.  For example, immediately save the value of GetLastError in a variable before calling any further functions, then use that variable to output the information.

Comment: For the record, volume access is subject to the same alignment rules as physical disk access.

Comment: @HarryJohnston True, but there are differences. Volume access can be performed by aligning to logical sector size (which is easy to obtain and almost universally 512 bytes for HDD on Windows), but physical access alignment is hardware dependent and not very easily obtainable.

Comment: @SeyedMohammad: I don't think that's true.  Windows should only care about the logical sector size, even when you're writing to a physical disk object.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, this is discussed in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Life is much easier with SetFilePointerEx

Comment: That article doesn't say anything about volume access and physical disk object access having different rules, so far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

This is unsurprising.  A volume is not a file, so it does not have an end-of-file position.

Windows *could* of course use the volume length as the end of file position, but there's no particular reason for it to handle this special case.

You will have to calculate the offset yourself.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the actual explanation, then this fact should've been mentioned in the "Remarks" section of the MSDN article for SetFilePointer function. I didn't see anything as such. Can you provide any references for this?

Comment: Microsoft don't generally document this sort of minutiae.  But check Rohan's answer - that could well be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to pass the non-NULL value for 3rd parameter in the api call.

```
result = SetFilePointer (vol_handle, dist, NULL, FILE_END);
//-----------------------------------------^
```

So change that to

```
LONG distToMoveHigh = 0;
result = SetFilePointer (vol_handle, dist, &distToMoveHigh, FILE_END);
...
```

The reason as mentioned on the MSDN page is

> If lpDistanceToMoveHigh is NULL and the new file position does not fit in a 32-bit value, the function fails and returns INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER.

As you are working with volume its likely to be > 2GB. So the `SetFilePointer()` api will not be able to return you new offset if its successful.

Comment: Nice point. I updated the question based on your answer, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @SeyedMohammad, Try printing value of distance high parameter even though API fails.

Comment: Have you tested to seek a volume handle from FILE_END on a Windows machine using a code similar to above? If it also fails for you (and other programmers) then I guess it means that Harry Johnston's explanation could be the answer.